# SQL - The fastest query for multiple INNERJOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, multiple-columns

Which query is faster - (or it doesn't matter)?

```
SELECT *
FROM students as s
INNER JOIN hallprefs as hp
    ON s.studentid = hp.studentid
INNER JOIN halls as h
    ON hp.hallid = h.hallid
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM students as s
INNER JOIN hallprefs as hp
INNER JOIN halls as h
    ON hp.hallid = h.hallid
    AND s.studentid = hp.studentid
```

Of course the original question is with way more tables.

Comment: When you ran both, which was faster in your tests?

Comment: You've got the queries, you've got the data: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Shouldn't matter, the optimizer is supposed to chose the fastest join order.

Comment: It's hard to say..
with few tables the differences is very tiny and my big query is very long.. 
besides - maybe in my case it will be different . I want to know if it's common knowledge

Comment: My comment above says it all. It doesn't matter!

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plans for both. I'll bet @jarlh is right and they're identical.

Comment: If they identical - which way is more correct?

Comment: The first one has valid ANSI SQL syntax, which means it's portable, i.e. good programming practice. Second one is MySQL only, bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have all alluded to the same points, that it shouldn't matter in terms of performance, and that the second query is not ANSI compliant. The reason MySQL allows it is because

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.

*extracted from [online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)*

So the ANSI equivalent of the second query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM students as s
CROSS JOIN hallprefs as hp
INNER JOIN halls as h
    ON hp.hallid = h.hallid
    AND s.studentid = hp.studentid;
```

Again, this rewrite should have no impact on performance, SQL is a declarative language, so you tell the engine what you want it to do, not how you want it to do it, so since the intention of the two queries is exactly the same, one would hope the optmiser arrives at the same plan for both. This is of course not always the case, although I am pretty certain it will be for all DBMS for simple cases like this.

When it comes to SQL, the answer to which is fastest/more efficient etc is almost always, it depends. It will depend on your schema, indexes, data types, data distribution, database vendor/version. So while general guidelines can be give, the real answer is to test.

As to which is better practice, I think it really depends on your intentions, The problem with the former is that you might decide you only want to left join on `halls`, so adapt your queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM students as s
CROSS JOIN hallprefs as hp
LEFT JOIN halls as h
    ON hp.hallid = h.hallid
    AND s.studentid = hp.studentid;
```

You introduce a Cartesian product, whereas the same change with the first query doesn't do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM students as s
INNER JOIN hallprefs as hp
    ON s.studentid = hp.studentid
LEFT JOIN halls as h
    ON hp.hallid = h.hallid;
```

Now, the intention could have been to have the Cartesian product, in which case the cross join solution is better for this situation. Once again, it depends, and your mileage may vary.